# D3.js cluster rollover - how to select and change another element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3.js and have altered an existing set of code to correctly display a circular cluster. I have added 'rect' items in an additional circle between the titles and the linking lines. My question is how do I set the corresponding 'rect' item to an 'on' class when rolling over the title. In the example from the following link, if I rollover 'Sample Item 1' I want the neighbouring rect box to change opacity to 1 and/or change the colour. Similarly if I roll over the rect box I want its title to change style (opacity and/or colour). So close and yet so far...

http://www.itq9.co.uk/d3/sample1

My thinking is that I need to add the correct selector the mouseoverd function:

```
function mouseovered(d) {
  node
   .each(function(n) { n.target = n.source = false; });

link
   .classed("link--target", function(l) { if (l.target === d) return l.source.source = true; })
   .classed("link--source", function(l) { if (l.source === d) return l.target.target = true; })
   .filter(function(l) { return l.target === d || l.source === d; })
   .each(function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); });

node
  .classed("node--target", function(n) { return n.target; })
  .classed("node--source", function(n) { return n.source; });

rect
  .classed("rect--target", function(r) { return r.target; })
  .classed("node--source", function(r) { return r.source; });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you need the mouseover handler only for the title elements, not for the rectangles -- you want something to happen when you mouseover the title, not the rect. To do this, you'll have to select the `rect` that corresponds to the title and change it. One way of doing this is to set IDs for the `rect` elements that allow them to be identified directly from the data bound to the titles. You haven't done this, so you can use D3's data matching and filtering to identify the element:

```
function mouseovered(d) {
  rect
.data(nodes.filter(function(n) { return !n.children; }))
    .filter(function(e) { return e == d; })
    // the selection will contain the corresponding rect element after this
    .attr("fill", ...);
}
```

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks so much for answering so quickly. This has really helped my understanding of D3.